# Taking the current Time and subtracting 3 hours from it

Tags: iphone

was wondering on how to take the current Time, and subtracting 3 hours from it to be stored in NSString?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setHour:-3];
NSDate *threeHoursAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:now options:0];
[comps release];
[calendar release];
```

I leave the output as an `NSString` to you (use `NSDateFormatter`).

Answer (score 4):

How about the [`[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: -3*60*60]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:) and using an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?